# GridView and Linq Query sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm using a `Linq` Query to populate a `GridView`.

Then I set it to the `Datasource`.

In the sorting event, I'd like to retrieve the the anonymous type that the query generates and find the members name.

**Is it possible to do so ?**

Here's an exemple of the query

```
var q = from inboundCall in dc.GetTable<InboundCall>()
join employee in dc.GetTable<Employee>() on inboundCall.EmployeeID equals employee.ID
join code in dc.GetTable<Code>() on inboundCall.CodeID equals code.ID
join site in dc.GetTable<Site>() on inboundCall.SiteID equals site.ID
where inboundCall.IsSuccess == true
                    select new
                               {
                                   EmployeeNumber = employee.Number,
                                   EmployeeName = employee.Name,
                                   CallerID = inboundCall.CallerID,
                                   SiteName = site.Name,
                                   CallDate = inboundCall.CallDate,
                                   CodeName = code.Name
                               };
```

And then

```
gridData.DataSource = q;
```

What can I do in the sorting event to retieve the Anonymous type and do something like that

```
employeeList.Sort((x, y) => ((Int32)x.GetType().GetProperty(e.SortExpression).GetValue(x, null)).CompareTo((Int32)y.GetType().GetProperty(e.SortExpression).GetValue(y, null)) * sortValue);
```

Comment: What member name do you need?  Can you give an example, some code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with reflection, or you could use the dynamic LINQ library to add the OrderBy clause.

Or, a better option may be to create an actual class / struct that represents the data you will be retrieving.

Comment: Yes, I already tought about creating a custom class, but how would I do it with reflection ?

Any thing you can point me to do it ? I can already do it with a grid binded on a table, using the first element on the list. But I don't know which casting I should do to be able to retrieve that information.

Any idea ?